# How to make author name hyperlinked to it's profile

Tags: 6, users

For my site this is the [sample page](http://www.articlesdirectoryindia.com/how-repair-corrupted-excel-file-0). Users are submitting articles and I (as admin) am creating myself a new page node and pasting the user article into it. At the same time I'm changing the author name to that of user's.

I've two questions:

- The author name( in this page it is some "clifflowe") is not hyperlinked to the user profile but when I see in as admin it is hyperlinked. How to make it hyperlinked for all users?
- Secondly after I create a new article page and simply change the author name with that of another user, will that user get any added permission on this article? Who is the original owner of this article then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the first question: users (anonymous or authenticated) need to have the "View user profiles" permission.

To the second: the user you set will be the original owner. The fact that admin created it is not stored in the node anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the first answer. Are you sure about the second answer? That Admin created it will never be known as if an authenticated user only created the page?

Comment: The Author is stored in the field uid. That is what you are changing. In D7 there is also a field called revision_uid that appears to store the uid of the user doing the actual (last) change. You can see this very clearly when you install the Devel module http://drupal.org/project/devel